# how to sort table when the data have two parts Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

this is my code i am getting the data from the server now how will i sort the table according to total ,remaining ,passed

```
function Dataset() {

    const [data,setData] = useState([]);
    const [toggleChoice,setToggleChoice] = useState(0);
    


    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
  
        <div className="dataset__container">
          <div className="dataset__header">
              <span className="dataset__title">Tabular hit/miss Data</span>
            <div className="toggleSwitch">
              <label for="hit" onClick={(e) => setToggleChoice(0)}>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  checked={toggleChoice === 0}
                  name="dataset"
                  id="hit"
                />
                <div className="actualRadio" id="leftSwitch">
                  hit
                </div>
              </label>
              <label for="miss" onClick={(e) => setToggleChoice(1)}>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  checked={toggleChoice === 1}
                  name="dataset"
                  id="miss"
                />
                <div className="actualRadio" id="rightSwitch">
                  miss
                </div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow style={{ background: "#34386b" }}>
                  <TableCell className="dataset__cell">ID</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className="dataset__cell" align="right">
                     Name
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className="dataset__cell" align="right">
                    Type
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className="dataset__cell" align="right">
                    Total
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className="dataset__cell" align="right">
                    Remaining
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className="dataset__cell" align="right">
                    Passed
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className="dataset__cell" align="right">
                    Failed
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className="dataset__cell" align="right">
                    Last Activity
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {data.map((row, index) => {
                  const main =
                    toggleChoice === 0 ? row.hit_data : row.missdata;

                  return (
                    <TableRow key={row.name}>
                      <TableCell
                        style={{ fontWeight: 600 }}
                        component="th"
                        scope="row">
                        {index + 1}
            
    );
}
```

can anyone would help me to add a button on passed head or remaining head such that after clicking all the data will be in increasing order or decreasing order and search bar all so that searching by name i will get filtered result

Comment: Use state variables to store the sort order, then make a copy of `data` and sort it, then render the copy.

Comment: can you show me how to do that

Comment: `const copy = [...data];` then `copy.sort(...)` depending on the sort order. Then `copy.map(...)` in your JSX.

Comment: can you say me in more detail like using button and how it will work

Comment: Sorry, no. This is not a free tutorial site. You need to do research, try stuff, debug it, etc. If you get really badly stuck, update your question with details and relevant code.

Comment: i tried all the stuff .and this is the whole relevent code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [sortBy,setSortBy] = useState('total'); //or remaining or passed
const [sortOrder,setSortOrder] = useState('asc');
const [data,setData] = useState([]);
const [toggleChoice,setToggleChoice] = useState(0);

const processedDataByChoice = useMemo(() => {
  return data.map((row, index) => {
    row.main = toggleChoice === 0 ? row.hit_data : row.missdata;
    return row;
  }
}, [data, toggleChoice])

const finalData = useMemo(() => {
  // sort 'processedDataByChoice' based on 'sortBy' and 'sortOrder'
  // return sorted value
  if (sortBy === 'total' && sortOrder === 'asc') {
    return processedDataByChoice.sort((rowA, rowB) => (rowA.main.total - rowB.main.total))
  } else if (sortBy === 'total' && sortOrder === 'desc') {
    return processedDataByChoice.sort((rowA, rowB) => (rowB.main.total - rowA.main.total))
  } else if (sortBy === 'remaining' && sortOrder === 'asc') {
    return processedDataByChoice.sort((rowA, rowB) => (rowA.main.remaining - rowB.main.remaining))
  } else if (sortBy === 'remaining' && sortOrder === 'desc') {
    return processedDataByChoice.sort((rowA, rowB) => (rowB.main.remaining - rowA.main.remaining))
  } 
  // add more conds
}, [sortBy, sortOrder, processedDataByChoice])


...

              <TableBody>
                {finalData.map((row, index) => {
                  const main = row.main
                  return (
                    <TableRow key={row.name}>
                      <TableCell
                        style={{ fontWeight: 600 }}
                        component="th"
                        scope="row">
                        {index + 1}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.name}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.type}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{main.total}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{main.remaining}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell style={{ color: "green" }} align="right">
                        {main.passed}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell style={{ color: "red" }} align="right">
                        {main.failed}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{main.last}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              </TableBody>

...
```

Comment: can you give me in more detail how to write sort processeddataby choice based on sort order and i want buttons too which will make them sort in increasing and decreasing order

Comment: Just use regular array sort()

Comment: but i want to sort when i click a increasing button how will i do that,would you help me with that too sorry i am new to react that's why i am asking you so much

Comment: Change sortBy and sortOrder value on button click

Comment: can you help me with that too